# How to have much lighter version of Spring Source Tool Suite?

Tags: grails, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

STS is over 350MB and most of it is corporate blubber ware that I do not need. For example its default installation includes bunch of Servers that shows up in project explorer and other things related to VMware cloud related products. All I need is Grails and Groovy and JavaScript related development and nothing else.

What is the procedure to remove all these things for clean and light installation of STS without destabilizing STS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose not to install tc server, Spring Roo and Apache Maven during the install.  Also, you can go under Help -> About SpringSource Tool Suite, click Installation Details..., and uninstall plugins you don't want.

Comment: Thanks. In my case I don't use the installer but I just copy the tar archive of STS and run the STS script to launch STS.

Comment: I think you should still be able to remove the other stuff under the installation details.  Or at the very least, stop them from loading.  

Though honestly, I've never noticed a problem with STS just installing the default plugins, it still starts in like 5 seconds and never has any performance issues (at least on an SSD).

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is already answered, but I just wanted to mention another way of installiong STS.  You can do this through update sites.  This way is slightly more complicated (only slightly), but does have the smallest footprint.  You can see the instructions here:

http://blog.springsource.com/2011/03/25/early-access-springsource-tool-suite-for-eclipse-indigo-3-7/